# Why does my code return True when it should be False if the number of substrings do not equal each other?

Tags: python, for-loop, count, substring

The goal is to return True if the number of times that the substring "cat" appears in str is equal to the number of times the substring "dog" appears in str.

I already solved this using the built-in `str.count(sub) method`, but now I have to use 1 loop. This isn't a homework problem, just for my own practice.

The test cases that don't work:

```
cat_dog('catxxdogxxxdog') --> True (should return False)
cat_dog('catxdogxdogxca') --> True (should return False)
cat_dog('dogdogcat') --> True (should return False)
```

Thank you!

```
def cat_dog(str):
  count1 = 0
  count2 = 0
  sub1 = 'cat'
  sub2 = 'dog'
  a = [sub1, sub2]
  if sub1 not in str and sub2 not in str:
    return True
  elif sub1 in str and sub2 not in str:
    return False
  elif str == '':
    return True
  for sub in a:
    if sub1 in str:
      count1 += 1
      if sub2 in str:
        count2 += 1
        if count1 == count2:
          return True
        else:
          return False
  else:
    return False
```

Comment: `if sub2` should be at the same level as `if sub1` and `if count` should be at `for level`

Comment: Have you used a debugger to see *why* it is returning `True` in these cases?

Comment: No I haven't. And even adjusting the indentation doesn't fix it.

Comment: If you don't know *why* it fails, how do you expect to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, that's *a lot* of code for what you want to do. Like, `str.count(substr)` would do your work.
But since you want to do it **WITHOUT** it, I wrote some code in the end.

Secondly, the code returns `False` for all test cases (as it should).

Here, this is a better version of the code you want (with some code suggestions in comments):

```py
# Have an indentation of 4 SPACES for Python
#  
# `str` is a bad identifier name (as its a built-in class)
# So try using similar variables which are NOT reserved by Python
# 
# Also, write some documentation for what the function does right
# after the `:` function definition (in three quotes, for multi-line docstrings)
# (These can be read by using the built-in helper function `help(cat_dog)`
def cat_dog(text=''):
    """
    Returns True if *text* has equal no. of 'dog' and 'cat' substrings
else returns False
    """

    # Since words are surrounded by other words and empty characters
    # we subtract 1 from the total
    dog_count = len(text.split('dog')) - 1
    cat_count = len(text.split('cat')) - 1

    return dog_count == cat_count
```

Here is another version, similar to the first, just in a different way:

```py
import re

def cat_dog(text=''):
    """
    same documentation
    """

    dog_count = len(re.findall('dog', text))
    cat_count = len(re.findall('cat', text))

    return dog_count == cat_count
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with this code segment:

```
for sub in a:
  if sub1 in str:
    count1 += 1
    if sub2 in str:
      count2 += 1
      if count1 == count2:
        return True
      else:
        return False
```

Here, you increment `count1` or `count2` by one if `sub` simply exists in `str`, it does not depend on how many times `sub` appears in the string. For example, `catxxdogxxxdog` produces `count1 = 2` and `count2 = 2` since the counts are both incremented once for each item in `a`.

If you don't want to use `str.count(sub)`, you will need to iterate through `str` yourself and count how many times each string appears.

Answer (score 0):

You're for loop isn't built to do what it is intended to. Everytime it loops, it finds that each of the substrings is in fact in the string, so it increments each count, you never handle anyway of stripping out that occurrence or moving onto the next occurence of that substring in future iterations of the loop.

That being said, I would recommend simply using the builtin `count` function to save yourself a good amount of time.

```py
def cat_dog(str):
  return str.count("cat") == str.count("dog")
```

Or if you still want to do it by hand without much complexity, might I recommend something like:

```py
def cat_dog(str):
    count1 = 0
    count2 = 0
    sub1 = 'cat'
    sub2 = 'dog'
    index = 0

    while sub1 in str[index:]:
        count1 += 1
        index = str[index:].find(sub1) + 1 +index

    index = 0

    while sub2 in str[index:]:
        count2 += 1
        index = str[index:].find(sub2) + 1 +index

    return count1 == count2
```